# Will this adaptor fit my cranks?

Tags: shimano, parts

Looking to adapt an old(er) set of FC-M952 XTR cranks to fit new chainrings (see [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/replacing-entire-group-need-new-hubs)).

Looking at [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/xtr-chainring-spider-94-58-Mountain-Bike-Silver-and-Vuelta/192039351952?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D38530%26meid%3Dd5930bf4844f41b0bda5a587067a9468%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D142218013647) auction - how would I determine whether or not I can use it? If it fits I'd also need to buy 9sp chainrings compatible with same old(er) XT/XTR system.

[image: Auction listing]

Comment: So you have the 5 arm version of this crankset?

Comment: This crankset is a weird one. The largest ring supports the other two and they don't make them anymore.

Comment: Sure. But, Sheldon Brown lists this crankset with the 2 outer rings as 4 bolt 112 bcd , whereas what you linked is not that.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the auction as it'll get removed from ebay eventually and this would otherwise turn into a dud question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in terms of compatibility, there's only one iteration of the Shimano 8-spline spider design that was used on various Shimano cranks, so the spider in question should work on all of them, including FC-M952.